# Draw glyph and WordWrap text together

Tags: delphi

I have a Canvas, Glyph, Text and variable Space as Integer. I want to draw Glyph and Text onto Canvas in according to TRadioGroup's ItemIndex (for example, if ItemIndex = 1 then draw Glyph by left side of the Text etc.)
In any cases Space must be inserted as a blank space between Glyph and Text.
Both, Glyph and Text must be centered onto Canvas, even if Canvas's width less then Glyph's width + Text's width.

I was trying to implement this task, but I was confused some calculations.
Attaching my code below:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  R1, R2: TRect;
  S: String;
  G, D: Integer;
  B, C: TBitmap;   
begin
  S := 'This is an example text to show how WordWrap works';
  B := TBitmap.Create;
  B.LoadFromFile('C:\g.bmp');

  C := TBitmap.Create;
  C.Width := 242;
  C.Height := 96;

  Form1.Repaint;
  Form1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clGreen;
  Form1.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, TrackBar1.Position, C.Height));

  // left
  if RadioGroup1.ItemIndex = 0 then
    begin
      R1 := Rect(B.Width + TrackBar2.Position, 0, TrackBar1.Position, C.Height);
      Form1.Canvas.TextRect(R1, S, [tfWordBreak, tfNoClip, tfCenter, tfCalcRect]);

      Form1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWebSkyBlue;
      R2 := Rect(B.Width + TrackBar2.Position, (C.Height - R1.Bottom) div 2, TrackBar1.Position, C.Height);
      Form1.Canvas.TextRect(R2, S, [tfWordBreak, tfNoClip, tfCenter]);

      Form1.Canvas.Draw((TrackBar1.Position - R1.Right - TrackBar2.Position) div 2, (C.Height - B.Height) div 2, B);
    end;

  //right
  if RadioGroup1.ItemIndex = 1 then
    begin
      R1 := Rect(B.Width + TrackBar2.Position, 0, TrackBar1.Position, C.Height);
      Form1.Canvas.TextRect(R1, S, [tfWordBreak, tfNoClip, tfCenter, tfCalcRect]);

      Form1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWebSkyBlue;
      R2 := Rect(0, (C.Height - R1.Bottom) div 2, TrackBar1.Position - B.Width - TrackBar2.Position, C.Height);
      Form1.Canvas.TextRect(R2, S, [tfWordBreak, tfNoClip, tfCenter]);

      Form1.Canvas.Draw((TrackBar1.Position + R1.Right - (B.Width*2) + TrackBar2.Position) div 2, (C.Height - B.Height) div 2, B);
    end;

  //top
  if RadioGroup1.ItemIndex = 2 then
    begin
      R1 := Rect(0, B.Height + TrackBar2.Position, TrackBar1.Position, C.Height);
      Form1.Canvas.TextRect(R1, S, [tfWordBreak, tfNoClip, tfCenter, tfCalcRect]);

      G := B.Height + R1.Bottom - R1.Top;
      D := (C.Height - G) div 2;

      Form1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWebSkyBlue;
      R2 := Rect(0, D + TrackBar2.Position, TrackBar1.Position, C.Height);
      Form1.Canvas.TextRect(R2, S, [tfWordBreak, tfNoClip, tfCenter]);

      Form1.Canvas.Draw((TrackBar1.Position - B.Width) div 2, D - TrackBar2.Position, B);
    end;

  //bottom
  if RadioGroup1.ItemIndex = 3 then
    begin
      R1 := Rect(0, B.Height + TrackBar2.Position, TrackBar1.Position, C.Height);
      Form1.Canvas.TextRect(R1, S, [tfWordBreak, tfNoClip, tfCenter, tfCalcRect]);

      G := B.Height + R1.Bottom - R1.Top;
      D := (C.Height + G) div 2;

      Form1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWebSkyBlue;
      R2 := Rect(0, D - R1.Bottom - R1.Top + B.Height + TrackBar2.Position, TrackBar1.Position, C.Height);
      Form1.Canvas.TextRect(R2, S, [tfWordBreak, tfNoClip, tfCenter]);

      Form1.Canvas.Draw((TrackBar1.Position - B.Width) div 2, D + TrackBar2.Position, B);
    end;

  FreeAndNil(B);
end;
```

How to use this code:
put two TrackBars onto Form and set their Max value in 242 for the first and in 10 for the second;
put TRadioGroup onto Form and set 4 items in its Items property in the next order: Left, Right, Top, Bottom.

So, when Left or Right item is chosen, the code work correctly (correctly - as I expect), but whe Top or Bottom item is chosen, Glyph and Text paintings not correct. I mean, for example, we choose item 'Top' and click Button1. What are we see? Right, Glyph is drawn on Text (see picture for more details). I have tried to defeat that but not successful, unfortunately:

[image: Top glyph's issue]

Well, is there any ways to improve this code? Or I should use another way to reach my goal?

P.S.
Sorry for my poor English ;)

EDIT
Update source code.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is `C´ supposed to be?

Comment: @TomBrunberg thank you! C is a TBitmap. I will add changes in the post.

Comment: Some extra tips, you should wrap `B` and `C` class variables in a try...finally statement. Also you should use `B.Free;` and not `FreeAndNil(B);` Finally you need to release `C` from memory, like so: `C.Free;`

Comment: @Craig, thank you for these tips, but there I show only working code to reproduce my problem. Assure you in real task I use more obvious names for variables; and of course I release all resources which have been taken in the code. But as I have said earlier, thank you for your tips ;)

Comment: @Dima I understand, I just wanted to comment in case you were not aware of these things. One final tip, instead of `Form1.Repaint` use `Form1.Invalidate` and you should call that at the end of the procedure when you finish drawing on the canvas ;)

Comment: @Craig, I will keep it in mind, thank you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculations for top and bottom are wrong.
And you can draw directly on the bitmap canvas instead of the form canvas.
Here is the fixed version:

```
  //top
  if RadioGroup1.ItemIndex = 2 then
    begin
      R1 := Rect(0, B.Height + TrackBar2.Position, TrackBar1.Position, C.Height);
      C.Canvas.TextRect(R1, S, [tfWordBreak, tfNoClip, tfCenter, tfCalcRect]);
      G := (C.Height div 2);
      // D is top for centered text rec + glyph size and spacing
      D := G + ((R1.Height + B.Height + Trackbar2.Position) div 2);
      C.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWebSkyBlue;
      R2 := Rect(0, D - R1.Height, TrackBar1.Position, D+R1.Height);
      C.Canvas.TextRect(R2, S, [tfWordBreak, tfNoClip, tfCenter]);
      C.Canvas.Draw((TrackBar1.Position - B.Width) div 2, R2.Top - B.Height - TrackBar2.Position, B);
    end;

  //bottom
  if RadioGroup1.ItemIndex = 3 then
    begin
      R1 := Rect(0, 0, TrackBar1.Position, C.Height);
      C.Canvas.TextRect(R1, S, [tfWordBreak, tfNoClip, tfCenter, tfCalcRect]);
      // G is absolute middle of draw canvas
      G := (C.Height div 2);
      // D is top for centered text rec + glyph size and spacing
      D := G - ((R1.Height + B.Height + Trackbar2.Position) div 2);
      C.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWebSkyBlue;
      R2 := Rect(0, D, TrackBar1.Position, D + R1.Height);
      C.Canvas.TextRect(R2, S, [tfWordBreak, tfNoClip, tfCenter]);
      C.Canvas.Draw((TrackBar1.Position - B.Width) div 2, R2.Bottom + TrackBar2.Position, B);
    end;
```

Comment: in your code I see "R1.Height". Delphi 2005 has no any "Height" for TRect, so I replaced this with "R1.Bottom - R1.Top". Is this correct? And when I tried to execute your code it works perfectly!! Thank you very much!

Comment: I am using XE7, so Bottom-Top is also fine.